# Why does Android API ask for a results parameter as opposed to a return method?

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization

My question is throughout the whole of the Android API a lot of the library calls ask for a `results[]` parameter to be passed into method for example:

```
public boolean isInProximity(double startLat, double startLongitude, float meters) {
    float[] results = new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(startLat, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);
    return results[0] <= meters;
}
```

The call to android is the `Location.distanceBetween()` and it requires the `results[]` why don't they just include a return signature to the method? I am assuming that it is some kind of memory or speed optimisation. I am unsure on the exact reasoning behind it.

Comment: Probably to give you the flexibility to pass in the same object (array in this case) to many invocations of the methods, thus preventing the need for allocation memory on each call.

Comment: So I assume that I am doing it wrong by having `private float[] results = new float[3];` @RobI

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you don't expect that method to get called often (for example, only as often as the user clicks a button), it will be unlikely to make a difference.  If your code is calling it millions of times, you could consider making that array a field to reduce allocations.

Comment: @Rob I don't see where you'd need a memory allocation in this case, *especially* in case of a register sized variable. Every calling convention ever invented (ok maybe you can find one that doesn't) will put such a return value into a register (r0, s0 or d0 in ARM's case I'd think). And even in case of a larger value, it will still get allocated on the stack which is pretty much as cheap as it can get.

Comment: @Voo we're talking about the result of the `Location.distanceBetween()` call, which is one to three floating point numbers.  This method above has been written by the asker.

Comment: @Rob Oh didn't see that it returned more than one value, makes a bit more sense. Still - at least hotspot - would be quite capable of changing the whole thing into a stack allocation, but at least early dalvik Jitter weren't anywhere close to sophisticated enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, it is about optimization, that way you can call this method many times without needing to allocate memory each time.

Edit -- 
Here is a test so: http://codeyarns.com/2010/10/21/c-return-value-versus-output-parameter/ 
Better late than never I guess.

Comment: This answer would be improved markedly by citing a reference or two.

Comment: Why would you have to allocate memory for returning a single - register sized - value? Even the most simplistic Jitter would just put the return value into `r0` (well `s0` here) on ARM - no memory at all being allocated..